# Map AWS Lambda 429 errors to API Gateway 2XX response

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I understand that by design, API Gateway maps 429 errors from Lambda to 500 responses.
Is there a way to map 429 to something else like 202?
I tried to create an integration response mapping from this regex: .*
which should map virtually everything to my defined status code, but i still receive 500 errors, from the API gateway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pasting my response from the AWS Forum [post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=228723&tstart=0):

> There is no way to map Lambda's 429 to any status code. It will always
>   be considered as 500. Curious to know, why do you want to map 429 to
>   202 (which means 'Accepted')?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Will be added in the future?
I have a huge load on Lambda on my production environment and I'm testing ways to handle the loads efficiently. While I want to keep it running in production for the scale, I don't want the cilents to be aware about the errors.
About 202, it actually makes sense, lets say if we log to CloudWatch all requests to API Gateway then the lambda returns 429 for some of them, then we could say that API Gateway '202 Accepted' the request and we can handle those requests later by querying CloudWatch.

Comment: I see. We do not have any plans to support this in the future. My suggestion would be:
1. Increase the Lambda throttling limit so that your API calls wouldn't be throttled. You don't pay for throttling limit increase, you only pay as you use. 
2. Use API Gateway to put the messages to SQS and return 202. In some interval, invoke Lambda function that will fetch a number of SQS messages and process them.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda 429 now maps to the INTEGRATION_FAILURE API Gateway response, so you can map it to any code you want, but keep in mind that will make any other integration error return that code as well. See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=309901